# Create multiple data with it's multiple parent table foreign key

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables, "transfers" and "storage_products". "storage_products" table has a foreign key "transfer_id" to get transfer info. Now let's say, I am trying to insert 2 transfers in the "transfer" table with some product data which will be stored in the "storage_products" table with its associate foreign keys. The backend scenario would be :

2 transfers will be created. Let's Transfer 1 has 2 products "a" and "b", and transfer 2 has 3 products "c", "d", "e". Now while someone submits the form, Transfer 1 and transfer 2 will be created in the "transfers" table. at the same time, it will create "storage products" with their associate transfer ids.

So the tables would looks like :

[image]

My codes so far are :

```
foreach ($request->product_id as $key => $value) {
    $input['product_id'] = $request->product_id[$key];
    $input['transfer_id'] = $request->transfer_id[$key];

    $storage_product[] = StorageProduct::updateOrCreate(['product_id'=>$request- 
    >product_id[$key]], $input);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can use $key for both product_id and transfer_id. You would need two separate loops. One time loop over the transfers, and one time over the products for each transfer.

Comment: Do you mean nested loop or just 2 different loops? in case of two different loops, how can I get different "transfer_id" for associate products in the stroage_product table

Comment: I would suggest a nested loop. Start by looping over all transfers and nest loop over the products for this transfer. Two separate loop should work as well, but I think larvel can manage adding parent and child in one go.